# Spring3 + hibernate

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate

I get this error in spring. nested exception is

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.

Why this error occured? Please help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a jar conflict somewhere.

If you have patience, you can look into this [Spring JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6575)

Comment: this interceptor is in the aopalliance.jar, but you need to make sure you don't have multiple versions of it.

Comment: @NicolasModrzyk ? I'd say it's in spring-aspects.jar